# MySQL: Query to COUNT number of times value in a column is equal to value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as such (minus the last column 'Subjob Count')

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqNmg.png)

how do I query such that I can generate the last column - i.e. count the number of jobs that have Job No. equal to the row's 'Parent Job No' ?

I tried

`SELECT jobNo, jobName, ParentJobNo, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs WHERE ParentJobNo = jobNo) FROM Jobs`

but this seems to check each row's JobNo with its own ParentJobNo (giving me 0)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the depth of the tree? Is it a two-level tree only, or can you have multiple/unlimited levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine, just use qualified column names:

```
SELECT j.jobNo, j.jobName, j.ParentJobNo,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs j2 WHERE j2.ParentJobNo = j.jobNo)
FROM Jobs j
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Is there a way to display a '-' instead of a 0 when the query is not applicable?

Comment: @karimbounekhla . . . You would need to convert the number to a string.  I don't recommend doing that in SQL (although you *can*).  Do it in the presentation layer.

Answer (score -1):

You need a recusive Query to find the Parent 'Job No'.

```
select j1.partenJobNo parent, j2.jobNo jobno from job j1 inner join job j2 where j1.partenJobNo = j2.jobNo.
```